# Java GUI - Adding text field

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm not really keen on Java GUI, but am learning as I go. I am in the process of making a very simple and basic Sudoku puzzle. Right now I am just on the basic layout of it.

I wanted to see if there was a simple way of adding a text field to each little rectangle that I have drawn out (81 total rectangles - 9x9 puzzle). So that a user can type something in there.

I am delving into it, but wanted to get the code up here to see if anyone had any tips, cause truth be told, I am mega lost with this.

Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        int coordinateX = 0;
        int coordinateY = 0;
        // maximum 9 rows
        int rows = 9;
        int columns = 1;

        // make a 9x9 puzzle
        while (columns <= rows) {
            //for loop to increment the boxes
            for (int j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
                // add and assign coordinte x... equivalent to x = x + 30
                coordinateX += 30;
                // where x and y determine start of the box and 30 determines the size
                g.drawRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 30, 30);
            } //end of for loop

            //reset the value of x to start a new row
            coordinateX = 0;
            coordinateY += 30;
            columns++;

        } //end of while loop


    } //end of void paint

} //end of class

public class DrawRect {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
        window.setVisible(true);

    } // end of void main

} // end of class
```

Hopefully someone has some pointers that could help me out, cause boy oh boy do I need it. Was kinda thrown into the lion's den without prior knowledge or practice, but I'm trying hard.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: My suggestion is that you get some IDE with Swing support, draw your stuff in a Swing editor and let it generate the code for your GUI. Much easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: I'd personnally use a GridLayout and multiple JTextFields instead of drawing rectangles. The borders of each JTF will draw the delimiters for you.

Comment: Better to download NetBeans IDE and you can drag and drop all the GUI components also you can align based on your wise.

Comment: @Yassin - could you elaborate please? Wouldn't I have to write out 81 separate text fields in that case? I don't know if you could use a loop to print out multiple text fields, as I am not familiar with Java GUI. Anything you can show me real quick please?

Comment: @rockymontana I posted an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`GridLayout(9,9)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and an array of arrays of `JTextField's`

This is, of course, just an example of how I would do it. There are other ways to do this.

Find below a generic example.

---

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextField[][] boxes = new JTextField[9][9];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,9));
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 9 ; j++){
            boxes[i][j] = new JTextField("0");
            frame.add(boxes[i][j]);
        }
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

### Output

[image: SolutionExample]

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds. Good answer.

Comment: @rockymontana You're welcome :D. Happy I made you happy.